# How can i access values in struct map?

Tags: c++, c++20

i'm working with smart pointers and i have a problem. Pls check me codes;

```
struct MyStr
{
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    int    salary;

};

typedef std::map<std::unique_ptr<MyStr>, std::unique_ptr<MyStr>> employee_map;
employee_map    m_emp;
```

and i need the find in map, but i'm not using `.find(x);` (have compiler error) and i'm coding new function like this;

```
auto FindInMap(auto prmt)
{
    const auto& it = std::find_if(m_emp.begin(), m_emp.end(),
        [&](const auto& emp) { return emp.first.get()->name == prmt; });
    return it;
}
```

and i'm using function like this;

```
const auto& it = FindInMap("Sam");
```

now i need the access `it->first->salary` or `it->second->salary` etc. how can I do that? My c++ version is `c++20`. I'm know i have a lot mistakes but sorry for shit codes i'm beginner :)

Comment: I'm not sure that map is the right shape of container for your purposes.  But if you are going to be looking things up by name, then the key type for the map should probably be `std::string`, not `std::unique_ptr`.  So maybe instead use `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<MyStr>>`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? As it stands, your code doesn’t make sense: your `FindInMap` defeats the purpose of using a map, and it’s unclear why your map is structured the way it is; why are you using `MyStr` both for the key and the value? What are you trying to map against what? And why are you using pointers? At a guess I’d say that `std::map<std::string, MyStr>` would be a more appropriate type (but the name `MyStr` throws me off as well, and obscures the purpose of the structure; *naming matters!*).

Comment: @KonradRudolph i need comparison two employee so i'm using key and value struct in map. Do you think using `unique_ptr` is unreasonable in terms of performance and speed?

Comment: @WayneCox Yes, it’s unreasonable: it doesn’t help, and adds unnecessary complexity. It’s even likely to *decrease* performance — What do you mean by “comparison”? The word has many meanings in very different contexts. What *exactly* is the data structure used for? How is it used? `std::map` has a fairly specific use-case and from your information so it’s impossible to determine if it’s suitable for your need (but it doesn’t look like it).

Comment: @KonradRudolph my purpose is pairing and transacting between employees

Answer (score 0):

I changed your function, keeping it functionally same but making it more explicit:

```
      employee_map::iterator FindInMap(const std::string& prmt)
      {
         const auto& it = std::find_if(m_emp.begin(), m_emp.end(),
            [&](const MyStr& emp) { return emp.name == prmt; });
         return it;
      }
```

Now, if I call

```
const auto& it = FindInMap("Sam");
```

I can now access `it->first` and `it->second`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: OK but this is almost certainly the wrong thing. You don’t want to use `std::find` with a map, it’s horrifically inefficient and defeats the sole purpose of using `std::map` in the first place.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes i need using `find` but when i try using `find` i have a compile error `E0304` and `C2661` how can i using `std::find` with this codes?

Comment: @WayneCox Perhaps you can create separate question and mention the link to that in this. Or you can update this question and I delete my answer. Either is fine (with me) :)